# FindWindow with partially known title

Tags: c#, pinvoke

Example Outlook: its only one process but can have multiple windows (user can double click on the email to open it in its own window)

So, I cannot use **Process.GetProcess()** to iterate through the processes and compare title.

**FindWindow()** needs full title; I know the title but Outlook window adds its own in the end i.e. - Message (Rich Text) or - Message (HTML) .. etc.

Can I get all the email windows (handles) for Outlook ? then iterate over those to find my window using **GetWindowText()** ? Any pointers will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use EnumWindow to enumerate through all the windows finding the one you want.

http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.enumwindows